# How to Read from a client and send to another client through a server socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, client

I have been suffering a huge problem in my server to send an object received from a client to another client. This object is a ChatMessage.
My server is able to send that message to the same client, but I can not think of a way to route this message to another client.

Please help
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If it helps once a client has a socket opened to the server, there is no difference between who is the server and who is the client. The server can initiate conversations also.

Answer (score 0):

The server needs both client connections open at the same time and a way to know that a message received from client-1 should be routed to client-2. Your protocol needs to handle BOTH client-to-server and server-to-client requests.

Answer (score 0):

There's any number of examples on the net for this. A quick google brought up this tutorial:

http://programming-guides.com/java/tcp-client-server-chat

You need to maintain multiple connections, one for each client, and send the data to the appropriate clients when you receive it.